# Gamedesign "group" html5 audio elements to mute and unmute

Tags: javascript, html, audio, var, mute

I am making a game, and I want to give the player the possibility to mute all sounds.

I call my audiofiles as following:

```
var STARTSCREEN     = new Audio('sounds/soundtrack-idle-24s.wav');
var GAMEPLAY        = new Audio('sounds/soundtrack-active-24s.wav');
var FX_BREAK        = new Audio('sounds/effect-break.wav');
var FX_BUBBLE       = new Audio('sounds/effect-bubble.wav');
var FX_EXPLOSION    = new Audio('sounds/effect-explosion.wav');
```

This works fine when I call the audio, for example, like this:

```
function startButtonClickHandler(event){
    GAMEPLAY.play();
}
```

I found a function to mute all sound with a button

```
muteButton = document.getElementById('mute-button');

function muteButtonClickHandler(event) {
    audio.muted = !audio.muted;
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

So I have to get all the audio 'grouped' as a `var` called `audio`.

But if i do the following, the whole thing breaks ('Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined'):

```
var audio = {
    STARTSCREEN     = new Audio('sounds/soundtrack-idle-24s.wav');
    GAMEPLAY        = new Audio('sounds/soundtrack-active-24s.wav');
    FX_BREAK        = new Audio('sounds/effect-break.wav');
    FX_BUBBLE       = new Audio('sounds/effect-bubble.wav');
    FX_EXPLOSION    = new Audio('sounds/effect-explosion.wav');
}
```

And how does my call change? Will it be something like:

```
audio.GAMEPLAY.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an object with audios:

```
var audio = {
  STARTSCREEN : new Audio('sounds/soundtrack-idle-24s.wav'),
  GAMEPLAY    : new Audio('sounds/soundtrack-active-24s.wav'),
  FX_BREAK    : new Audio('sounds/effect-break.wav'),
  FX_BUBBLE   : new Audio('sounds/effect-bubble.wav'),
  FX_EXPLOSION: new Audio('sounds/effect-explosion.wav')
};
```

Now you can call `play()` method of each audio like this:

```
audio.GAMEPLAY.play();
```

To mute/unmute all audios iterate through this object:

```
function toggleMute() {
  for (var i in audio) {
    audio[i].muted = !audio[i].muted;
  }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot, the solution was very simple. I'm just a rookie when it comes to programming.

Comment: If this answer solved your issue or answered your question then please accept it as the right answer.